# How can I display the TreeView, but not the Quick Launch on 1 page Onlly

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have one page where I need to hide the Quick Launch, but display the Tree view.  I wanted to do this via a webpart.  The below code hides the QuickLaunch, but also hides the TreeView ?  How do I display the TreeView only for a particular page...

```
<style>#sideNavBox { DISPLAY: none }#contentBox { margin-left: 0px }</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enable Tree View from Site Settings > Look & Feel > Tree View. Keep both Quick Launch and Tree View enabled.
If you want Tree View to be hidden from all the page then apply following CSS in your master page(which all the pages are using) which will keep Tree View hidden in all the pages.

```
<style>
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_TreeViewNavigationManagerV4
{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Now add following CSS to your page where you want to show Tree View not Quick Launch.

```
​​<style>
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_QuickLaunchNavigationManager
{
    display:none;
}
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_TreeViewNavigationManagerV4
{
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this today and it worked perfect.